# Dropbox Python API: Uploading a file

Tags: python, python-2.7, dropbox, dropbox-api

I would like to know how to use the `dropbox` library in Python 2.7 to upload a file to my Dropbox.

I have successfully connected to my Dropbox and the Dropbox object is called db.

How to do this?

Comment: By `the dropbox object` you mean the `DropboxClient`?

Comment: I mean the class dropbox.Dropbox()

Comment: Have you _tried_ anything and run into a problem? If so, post your code and the error. Or are you just asking us to post a link to [the documentation](http://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moduledoc.html#dropbox.dropbox.Dropbox.files_alpha_upload)?

Comment: I don't believe the `Dropbox` class is meant for public consumption because they don't document it on their API docs - I only found it in the source code. Do you mind a solution with the `DropboxClient`, that is the one I'm familiar with and that's also the one that is documented for public use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Dropbox Python SDK](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/python) provides both API v1 and API v2 functionality for backwards compatibility, but only API v2 should be used now, as API v1 is [deprecated](https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2016/06/api-v1-deprecated/). The [tutorial](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/python#tutorial) covers the basic of using the API v2 functionality.

---

---

This uses the [Dropbox Python SDK](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-python) to download a file from the Dropbox API at the remote path `/Homework/math/Prime_Numbers.txt` to the local file `Prime_Numbers.txt`:

```
import dropbox
dbx = dropbox.Dropbox("<ACCESS_TOKEN>")

with open("Prime_Numbers.txt", "wb") as f:
    metadata, res = dbx.files_download(path="/Homework/math/Prime_Numbers.txt")
    f.write(res.content)
```

`<ACCESS_TOKEN>` should be replaced with your access token.

---

---

And for uploading:

This uses the [Dropbox Python SDK](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-python) to upload a file to the Dropbox API from the local file as specified by `file_path` to the remote path as specified by `dest_path`. It also chooses whether or not to use an upload session based on the size of the file:

```
f = open(file_path)
file_size = os.path.getsize(file_path)

CHUNK_SIZE = 4 * 1024 * 1024

if file_size <= CHUNK_SIZE:

    print dbx.files_upload(f.read(), dest_path)

else:

    upload_session_start_result = dbx.files_upload_session_start(f.read(CHUNK_SIZE))
    cursor = dropbox.files.UploadSessionCursor(session_id=upload_session_start_result.session_id,
                                               offset=f.tell())
    commit = dropbox.files.CommitInfo(path=dest_path)

    while f.tell() < file_size:
        if ((file_size - f.tell()) <= CHUNK_SIZE):
            print dbx.files_upload_session_finish(f.read(CHUNK_SIZE),
                                            cursor,
                                            commit)
        else:
            dbx.files_upload_session_append(f.read(CHUNK_SIZE),
                                            cursor.session_id,
                                            cursor.offset)
            cursor.offset = f.tell()

f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

**Note**

This is API v1, which is now being deprecated. Use with care or use the currently supported APIs.

**Initialize Dropbox client**

```
import dropbox
access_token = 'SOME_ACCESS_TOKEN'
client = dropbox.client.DropboxClient(access_token)
```

**Upload file**

```
src_file = open('SOME_LOCAL_FILE', 'r')
response = client.put_file('SOME_REMOTE_FILE', src_file)
```

**Download file**

```
dest_file = open('SOME_LOCAL_FILE', 'w')
with client.get_file('SOME_REMOTE_FILE') as src_file:
    dest_file.write(src_file.read())
```

**Reference**

For more concise API documentation please refer to [Core API for Python Documentation](https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/docs/python)

Comment: Thank you very much! I will test it soon (~30 minutes) and mark this answer as accepted if it works.

Comment: This code uses the deprecated API v1, which will be turned off in 2 months.

Comment: @Rawing Thx for the heads up. I used this API years ago and I didn't realize it was being pushed out. I'll note that on my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
f = open(file_path)
file_size = os.path.getsize(file_path)
CHUNK_SIZE = 4 * 1024 * 1024

if file_size <= CHUNK_SIZE:
    print dbx.files_upload(f, dest_path)
else:
    upload_session_start_result = dbx.files_upload_session_start(f.read(CHUNK_SIZE))

    cursor = dropbox.files.UploadSessionCursor(session_id=upload_session_start_result.session_id, offset=f.tell())
    commit = dropbox.files.CommitInfo(path=dest_path)

    while f.tell() < file_size:
        commit = dropbox.files.CommitInfo(path=dest_path)    
        if ((file_size - f.tell()) <= CHUNK_SIZE):
            print dbx.files_upload_session_finish(f.read(CHUNK_SIZE),                               
                                                          cursor,
                                                          commit)
        else:
            dbx.files_upload_session_append(f.read(CHUNK_SIZE),cursor.session_id, cursor.offset)
           cursor.offset = f.tell()
```